# Не завершается выполнение Java программы

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть такой простой код с потоками:

```
public class App {

    private static volatile boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable hellos = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Hello " + i);
            }
            done = true;
        };

        Runnable goodbyes = () -> {
            int i = 1;
            while (!done) i++;
            System.out.println("Goodbye " + i);
        };

        Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.execute(hellos);
        executor.execute(goodbyes);
    }
}
```

не могу понять, по какой причине данная программа никогда не завершается? Как можно "диагностировать" проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте в конце кода executor.shutdown()
Нужно закрыть Executor Service.

Comment: Понятно. А в каких случаях используется `ExecutorService`, а в каких `Executor`? У `Executor` только один метод - `execute`.

Comment: Executor не надо использовать . Это интерфейс, который имплементится Executor Service'ом .

Comment: shotdown() Для мягкого завершения - пул уже не принимает заданий, но дает завершится уже начатым (при этом если у вас бесконечный цикл, то надо использовать shotdownNow()) . shotdownNow() - пул уже не принимает заданий и любыми путями пытается прибить текущие задания (interrupt() итд)